# What do you call people that eat fish but not meat?

Tags: fish, vegetarian

Is it proper to identify people who eat fish but not meat as a class of vegetarians, or is there a better word to describe these group of people (who generally find pulses including beans, broad beans, chick peas, and lentils a perfect substitute for meat but deeply regret the fact that fish fats needed by the hunan body are not available elsewhere)?

Comment: Fish fats are NOT required by the human body. There are lots of names, from different cultures. AFAIK none are scientific or medical categories etc.

Comment: Could this not have been answered by a simple google search?

Comment: I'm a lacto-ovo pescatarian, but since so many people don't know what that is I usually just tell them that I have a trendy eating disorder. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vegetarians don't eat any animals including fish. Those who don't eat meat but fish are called **pescetarians**. For practical reasons, sometimes pescetarians say that they are vegetarians, as [Joe says in his answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/55467/23376) in [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/46964/23376):

> I read something recently (might've been a blog, might've been some
>   online publication), explaining why the person called themselves a
>   vegetarian and yet would eat fish:
>
> - Because it was easier than explaining all of their can/can't eat items.
>
> Many people aren't familiar with the term 'pescatarian', and if
>   someone invites you to a dinner party, it's easier to just say 'I'm a
>   vegetarian' than 'I'm a lacto-ovo pescetarian' and have to take the
>   time explaining what it means. If they prepare vegetarian food, you
>   can eat it ... they don't need to know the whole ontology of different
>   types of vegetarianism.

Answer (score 1):

The word is *[pescetarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pescetarianism)*.

5 characters right here.